# Why is my home network so slow?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, cable-modem

**Update 1** posted below.

---

At home we have a cable internet service (Comcast/Xfinity). I have an owned [Netgear CM400 Cable Modem](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/cable-modems-routers/CM400.aspx). The modem is connected to a wireless router to provide both wired and wireless connections to devices across the home.

I am using the [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) and [fast.com](http://fast.com) services to measure internet connection speeds.

When connected directly to the modem network port, I measure connection speeds of around 240 Mbps. However, once connected through the router, the speed is reduced dramatically. Particularly over WiFi, and by dramatically, I mean speeds less than 1 Mbps. Interestingly, the upload speeds are consistently higher then the download speeds.

For a long time I had an [On Networks N150R Wireless-N router](https://www.on-networks.com/images/uploaded/N150R_IG_11MAY2012.pdf) connected. With time, the connection speeds got that slow. Trying to troubleshoot, I noticed that when power-cycling the modem and router, the speed increases for a short while, but then it returns to a crawling speed.

Because the directly connected speed is very fast, I assumed the router was the problem.

So, I took an older, [eHome EH100 Wireless-G router](https://setuprouter.com/router/ehome/eh100/manual-2152.pdf) and replaced the OnNetwork one. But again, speeds were very low.

As a last resort, I ordered a [Linksys AC1000 Wireless-AC router](https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-E5350/) to replace the eHome router. Thinking the old-ish cheapo routers were the problem, I was expecting a very fast connection out of the new router. But to my demise, the speeds were improved but remain in the low single-digit range.

Which makes me now wonder if the problem may actually be the modem itself. I don't know how it is possible, and not sure how things work, but is it possible that once the modem is connected to a router, then the routing protocol creates a problem with the modem's downlink connection?

Note that all 3 routers are 10/100 Mbps routers and not GigE. The laptop and modem are GigE, which is why I can measure the 240 Mbps on direct connection.

---

Details on connecting to the admin servers of both devices:

The CM400 modem indicated a good cable connection. The cable transmission power levels of both directions are within Netgear recommended ranges. Looking at the event log file shows some T3 timeout events, but from what I could gather, this frequency is normal (is it so?):

```
Time                  Priority      Description
Time Not Established  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Aug 21 16:53:05 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Sep  3 09:31:12 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep  3 09:34:10 2020  Critical (3)  SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Loss of Sync
Sep  3 09:38:11 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep  9 12:08:05 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Sep 10 00:46:58 2020  Warning  (5)  RCS Partial Service
Sep 15 08:47:44 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 15 08:47:44 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 15 09:00:22 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 15 09:00:23 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 16 16:25:04 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Sep 16 16:25:05 2020  Warning  (5)  RCS Partial Service
Sep 19 07:18:15 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 19 07:18:31 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 19 07:18:31 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 19 07:19:51 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 19 07:19:51 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 19 07:20:09 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 19 07:20:09 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 19 07:20:28 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 19 07:20:28 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 19 07:20:48 2020  Critical (3)  Unicast Ranging Received Abort Response - initializing MAC
Sep 19 07:20:48 2020  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 19 07:21:25 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Sep 19 07:33:39 2020  Critical (3)  Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 24 21:06:08 2020  Warning  (5)  Lost MDD Timeout
Time Not Established  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 28 12:19:47 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Sep 28 13:05:36 2020  Critical (3)  Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 29 20:27:31 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Time Not Established  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Sep 30 12:53:58 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Time Not Established  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Oct  1 07:07:08 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Time Not Established  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Oct  1 20:38:34 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Time Not Established  Critical (3)  No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out
Oct  2 02:46:51 2020  Warning  (5)  MIMO Event MIMO: Stored MIMO=-1 post cfg file MIMO=-1
Oct  2 02:59:02 2020  Critical (3)  Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - T3 time-out
```

In the Linksys router's admin server I applied the ping test to [www.comcast.com](http://www.comcast.com):

```
PING 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b(2600:1401:2000:18b::20b) 32 data bytes

40 bytes from 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 Time=16.3 ms
40 bytes from 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=9.86 ms
40 bytes from 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=22.3 ms
40 bytes from 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 Time=11.7 ms
40 bytes from 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b: icmp_seq=5 ttl=60 time=11.4 ms

--- 2600:1401:2000:18b::20b data statistics ---

5 Packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% Packet loss, Time 4016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.860/14.348/22.380/4.569 m
```

---

**Any idea what could be the cause of this problem, and how to solve it?**

If you think there is a better SE site to ask this, please let me know.

---

**Update 1**:

After talking to a Comcast rep, she got to the conclusion that the problem was the modem itself, who claim to have ran some diagnostics from her side, and it needs replacement or a fix. One limitation being this is not a leased (nor specifically approved) modem, so she could not do further remote testing.

But I did go through the following:

1. Used [speedtest.xfinity.com](http://speedtest.xfinity.com) as the test server
2. Connected the test laptop directly to the modem
3. Examine the SNR and signal strength in the modem admin server
4. Factory-reset the modem (using the reset pushbutton and using the admin server)
5. Finally, move the modem to *before* the cable splitter (so it is connected directly to the wall with a single coax)

What I observed is the following:

1. Once the modem is rebooted the connection speed is more than 200Mbps, as expected. However, as time passes, the speed begins dropping severely. After 20 minutes it is back at the crawling speed.
2. Whenever I change the device connected to the modem (i.e., change router or switch to laptop) I need to restart the modem to get connected to the internet. Thus, after each device switch, the measure speed is great. It is only after some time that it drops. This fact caused me to initially believe that direct PC connection was OK.

Is this normal to restart the modem on each switch? Why don't I need to do that when connecting to the router's LAN ports?

I will try replacing the modem and see if it gets fixed. If not, then the problem is definitely with the coax wiring or the street-to-home connection itself.

Comment: Is the slowness only on Wi-fi?  What if you're wired to the router?

Comment: T3 errors usually mean a ISP equipment problem at the street level. Call your ISP, mention the critical errors, it should get someone dispatched to fix it...

Comment: @RonTrunk - yes, it is slow also on wired connection (but not as slow as WiFi).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - thanks. If you examine the log, you'll see a relatively slow rate of T3's. From what I read, this is not unexpected, and in anyway, it does not seem to affect the non-routed connection speed (direct PC-to-modem).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - This is observed when there is as low as a single WiFi client active, as much as when there are multiple, video streaming ones.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - This is my understanding when reading this guide: https://pickmymodem.com/cable-modem-t3-and-t4-timeouts-error-messages-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - about STB's - I assume you refer to the DVR? If so, how is this related to wireless issues, and why would this have an effect on the network-through-3-routers but not network-directly? I can experiment and remove the DVR from the coax, but I don't really see how it comes into play.

Comment: "When T3 timeouts occur, but not enough occur in succession to trigger a reset, slow speeds are often a symptom as these timeouts slow down the TCP/IP handshakes necessary to maintain internet connections." ~ you fall into this category. I will admit it's odd, that wired is working better, either way you should clear up the upstream errors. Something is going on with either the modem, inside wiring, or the local street level equipment. See what you can do from your end. This can even come down to a bad splitter inline with the modem!

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - thanks. But, assuming the modem logs all incidents, and that it only happens very few times a day, how is this a symptom of constantly experiencing a very slow connection? And why only via the router(s)? (sorry, you updated your comment while I was writing my reply)

Comment: I'll try connecting the modem before the splitter and see.

Comment: It's also not unheard-of to have a single interface go bad on these. I have never personally seen it be the wireless only. It was usually the docsis interface. (And that usually came down to some sort of static/ lightning event damaging the equipment because if improper grounding on the incoming online to the house) might want to check the grounding block too, it's necessary to maintain shield grounding throughout the whole system. If it looks corroded in anyway (not shiney but dull or oxidized) it should be replaced, or cleaned up with a brass brush and re-terminated.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment was assuming it was a triple play device. Which it isn't. (Grounding is still important to maintain a proper SNR though)

Comment: To see what the WiFi signal looks like real-time, try a utility such as Nirsoft's free WSiFiInfoView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html . Also try manually other channels.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - thanks for the recommendation NirSoft's utility collection is so awesome! Downloading and running WiFiInfoView, I see that my two wireless networks (2.4GHz and 5GHz) have a very high average signal quality (>90), and more than twice than the next (neighbour's) networks. However, the channel utilization is a miserable ~1%, as expected from such a slow download rate.

Comment: Log in to the modem and see if you can set the interface speed manually to match that of the WAN port on the router. Having a mismatch in capabilities between these two devices can reduce your speed because packets will be dropped as one device can not handle the traffic from the other device. Often times there are terrible buffer handling algorithms on these devices which compound the situation. You should be using a gigabit capable router.

Comment: @Appleoddity - thanks. Unfortunately, AFAICT I do not have such setting in my modem admin interface. The only user setting there is the start frequency for registration during modem init.